# R Read and Edit LAS Files

Tags: r

I'm having trouble using the rlas & rLiDAR packages for reading in & editing LAS files.  I run through the examples on their PDF documents, but I keep getting errors.  Below is for the rlas package.

```
> lasfile <- system.file("LAS", "42389364730000.las", package = "rlas")
> lasdata <- rlas::readlasdata(lasfile)
ERROR: wrong file signature '~Version Information
 VERS.                 2.0: 
 WRAP.                 YES: 
 END.                PE'
ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name 'C:\Users\Paul.Victor\Documents\R\R-3.4.3\library\rlas\LAS\42389364730000.las'
Error: LASlib internal error. See message above.
```

Below is the rLiDAR error...

```
> lasfile <- system.file("LAS", "42389364730000.LAS", package = "rLiDAR")
> 
> lasdata <- readLAS(lasfile, short = TRUE)
Error in readLAS(lasfile, short = TRUE) : 
  The LASfile input is not a valid LAS file
```

I've saved my LAS file in each package's folder in my system.file() similar to the examples on their PDFs.  Any help to resolve these issues or direct me to a different library would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the library you are using is designed for Lidar LAS files, and the file you are trying to read is the well log LAS file format... two different disciplines/data types with the same file extension.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the filepath correctly. If you want to access the example file, you could use `system.file` function, but like so:

```
> library(rlas)
> lasfile <- system.file("extdata", "example.laz", package = "rlas")
> lasdata <- rlas::readlasdata(lasfile)
> str(lasdata)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  30 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ X                : num  339003 339003 339003 339003 339004 ...
 $ Y                : num  5248001 5248000 5248000 5248000 5248000 ...
 $ Z                : num  976 975 974 974 974 ...
 $ gpstime          : num  269347 269347 269347 269347 269347 ...
 $ Intensity        : int  82 54 27 55 117 81 84 104 91 99 ...
 $ ReturnNumber     : int  1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ NumberOfReturns  : int  1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ScanDirectionFlag: int  1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ EdgeOfFlightline : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ Classification   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ScanAngle        : int  -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 -21 ...
 $ UserData         : int  32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
 $ PointSourceID    : int  17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

See [here](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/rlas/tree/master/inst/extdata) to see where the file is located.

To import your own file, just specify the correct path, e.g.

```
lasfile <- C:/Users/Paul.Victor/Documents/myproject/myfile.laz
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested with making the lasfile just the path to my las, but I still get the error at the end of my code...

Comment: > library(rlas)

> lasfile <- "N:\\SanAntonio\\Dept\\DataAnalytics\\Public\\Automated Jobs\\MudLogLoader\\MUD_LOGS_ARCHIVE\\42389364730000.LAS"

> lasdata <- rlas::readlasdata(lasfile)

ERROR: wrong file signature '~Version Information
 VERS.                 2.0: 
 WRAP.                 YES: 
 END.                PE'
ERROR: cannot open lasreaderlas with file name 'N:\SanAntonio\Dept\DataAnalytics\Public\Automated Jobs\MudLogLoader\MUD_LOGS_ARCHIVE\42389364730000.LAS'
Error: LASlib internal error. See message above.